# Datepicker not clearing the edge of table

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, reactstrap, react-datepicker

I'm having a rather stubborn `DatePicker` that I can't seem to get to behave.
I'm using `react-datepicker`'s `DatePicker` component.

I have a table, where each row has a `DatePicker`. Opening the calendar view of the date picker seems to not clear the edge of the table:

[image: picture of calendar with the bottom row cut off by the table]

I **have** tried setting `style={{zIndex: "9999 !important"}}` on the table to no avail.
This appears to be the only solution anyone ever recommends.

The bit of code using the DatePicker component looks like this:

```js
<Row>
    <Col>
        <DatePicker
            onChange={onChangeCallback(user.id)}
            autoComplete="off"
            shouldCloseOnSelect={false}
            dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"
            selected={date}
            placeholderText="Vælg Dato..."
            clearButtonTitle="Ryd"
            isClearable
        />
    </Col>
    <Col>
        <Calendar
            color="#ff7e01"
            className="align-middle"
            size={18}
        />
    </Col>
</Row>
```

with `Row` and `Col` imported from `reactstrap`.

Interestingly, the DatePicker acts correctly when not using `Row` and `Col`, so something in there must be causing this interference.

Any clues?

Comment: @isherwood I'm a back-end dev on front-end duty. How do I do any of this?

Comment: At a quick glance, you might find a [property](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker/blob/master/docs/datepicker.md) to change where the popup attaches to the DOM.

Comment: Otherwise, inspect the page with your browser and see what element has `overflow: hidden`. Try changing that to `visible` and see if your layout blows up.

Comment: I did try setting `overflow: visible`, that didn't work either

Comment: I tink there is an overflow:hidden on the Col / Row, have you tried changing those as well?

Comment: I set it on the row and the col and the component itself, and it still doesn't clear the table. Is it perhaps because I'm doing it in-line with the component rather than using actual CSS?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64254322/react-date-picker-is-being-hidden-behind-overflow-parent-popover-fixed-placemen

Comment: doesn't seem to do anything either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know [you've already tried the `position: fixed` option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70942394/datepicker-not-clearing-the-edge-of-table/70971443#comment125413280_70942394), but as [ccallendar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/306389/ccallendar) [alludes to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64254322/react-date-picker-is-being-hidden-behind-overflow-parent-popover-fixed-placemen#comment123968441_64256411), the library `@popperjs/core` used by `datepicker-react` has changed since then, more specifically:

> "**7. Change positionFixed**
>
> In Popper 2, this is now the strategy option:
>
> ```js
> createPopper(reference, popper, {
>   strategy: 'fixed',
> });
> ```
>
> "
>
> -- https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/migration-guide/#7-change-positionfixed

Applying that to your question, then this should work:

```js
<Row>
    <Col>
        <DatePicker
            onChange={onChangeCallback(user.id)}
            autoComplete="off"
            shouldCloseOnSelect={false}
            dateFormat="dd-MM-yyyy"
            selected={date}
            placeholderText="Vælg Dato..."
            clearButtonTitle="Ryd"
            isClearable
            popperProps={{ strategy: "fixed" }}
        />
    </Col>
    <Col>
        <Calendar
            color="#ff7e01"
            className="align-middle"
            size={18}
        />
    </Col>
</Row>
```

Comment: you saved my day TTYYY