# DatePicker Overly hiding under modal using MUI with react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

The Parent Component is MUI `Page` then `modal` which is also from MUI and then inside the modal, I'm rendering the DatePicker

```
// @mui
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers';
```

That's how it is being rendered.

```
    <Controller
        name="createDate"
        control={control}
        render={({ field, fieldState: { error } }) => (
          <DatePicker
            label="Date create"
            value={field.value}
            onChange={(newValue) => {
              field.onChange(newValue);
            }}
            renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} fullWidth error={!!error} helperText={error?.message} />}
          />
        )}
      />
```

But the problem is that `DatePicker` overly displays under the modal. How can I make changes so that can be fixed?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64254322/react-date-picker-is-being-hidden-behind-overflow-parent-popover-fixed-placemen) question's solution but it didn't help. The reason might be these answers are not for the MUI DatePicker. So I need your help fixing this. Thanks.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

change the zIndex for the modal component `<Modal sx={{zIndex: 3}} ... >`